# iPhone security architecture

Tags: iphone

I want to study in detail about security architecture that iphone has implemented. after searching on internet, the only useful material that i found is iphone reference library. Where i am now a days studying the Architecture of OS and then i will seduty the "secure coding guide".

I was wondering, if some of you guys, can lead me to some nice article or something which covers iphone security in general or in detail besides iphone official sites.

thanks,

Comment: I believe this belongs on Super User, given that it is related to the OS and not any programming-related issue.

Comment: there might be some app development issues as well. like seucrity related to accessing system resources, some restrictions on files etc. thats why i put it here.